# restarting a systemd user service from within cron

Tags: cron, systemd

I have a user `test`.

`test` has a systemd user service, located at `/home/test/.config/systemd/user/testserv.service`

The service file contains,

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Service
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/test/test_website
ExecStart=/home/test/venv/bin/gunicorn \
    --access-logfile \
    - \
    --workers 2 \
    --bind unix:/home/test/test_website/test_website.sock run:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I would like to restart this service every 5 minutes, from within cron.

For this, I created a script `/home/test/test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH="/home/test/venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
HOME="/home/test"
SHELL="/bin/bash"

exec &>> log.txt

systemctl --user restart testserv.service
```

And ran it from within `test`'s crontab, as,

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/test/test.sh
```

But I keep getting this error, and I'm unable to figure out the reason.

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these lines before you restart the service:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/bus
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
```

Found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474440